Only some commands functioning on ADB (Qin F21 Pro)
I've had a Qin F21 Pro for a while.
I always used adb to uninstall system apps from --user 0. However ever since I installed a System update (to version 1.1.8) I can't preform some commands (the device connects and shows up). adb push /pull still work for example, but other commands including install/uninstall just say failure
Here's an example:
C:\platform-tools-latest-windows\platform-tools>adb shell pm list packages
Failure

C:\platform-tools-latest-windows\platform-tools>adb shell pm uninstall --user 0 com.browser.android
Failure

C:\platform-tools-latest-windows\platform-tools>adb install C:/k9.apk
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install C:/k9.apk: Failure

I'm not an expert and this device is unrooted and i prefer not to root. Please advise what could be done.
I've tried anything I could think of.

revoke usb debugging
used Wifi debugging
Tested on another laptop so I don't think it's a driver issue.


adb install is in the end a shortcut for the two commands adb push and adb shell pm install. May be you get a more detailed error message when you execute pm install manually.

Did that and I got failure again. @Robert

Try adb shell first and then check interactively what works and what doesn't, and perhaps the reason why

Of course you will get an error again, the reason why I suggested to run directly pm install is that is might output a more detailed error message. You can also execute adb logcat in a second terminal while executing pm install multiple times to see if it contains an error message or stack trace every time you execute pm install.

I've tried as many commands as possible (inc. pm install and in adb shell ) but no more details have come up. Just failure . Am gonna try the adb logcat , when I get the chance. Has anyone ever heard of a software update that does this?

I tried adb logcat and couldn't make much out of it. However I tried shizuku and got fatal: can't get path of manager info: shizuku_starter exit with non - zero value - 7 . What can this be?
